# What is the difference between {0} and ""?

Tags: c

I would like to know if there is a difference between:

```
char s[32] = "";
```

and:

```
char s[32] = {0};
```

Thanks.

Comment: The answer has been given. But just in case you should think now there's no difference between `{0}` and `""`, try this with other types, for instance, `int` arrays instead of `char` arrays. Then you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No there is no difference between both declarations:

```
char bla[32] = {0};

and

char bla[32] = "";
```

See the relevant paragraph of the C Standard (emphasis mine):

> (C99, 6.7.8p21) "If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, **or fewer characters in a string literal** used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage  duration."

Comment: That is, as long as `'\0' == 0`.

Comment: @Philip I don't have a quote from the Standard but here is what K&R 2nd says *"The character constant '\0' represents the character with value zero, the null character. '\0' is often written instead of 0 to emphasize the character nature of some expression, but the numeric value is just 0."*

Comment: In n1570, it's 6.4.4.4, points (5) and (10), also (12). `'\0'` is just another way to write the `int` 0.

Answer (score 10):

In that case, there's no difference, both initialise all slots of the array to 0. In general, `""` works only for `char`  arrays (with or without modifications like `const` or `unsigned`), but `{0}` works for arrays of all numeric types.

In section 6.7.9 of the standard (n1570), point 21 reads

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members
>   of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known
>   size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

so even `""` initialises the complete array.

Comment: +1 `{0}` works for any data type that is allowed to have an initializer. On the other hand it *isn't* allowed for all arrays, namely not for VLA, since these mustn't have initializers.

Answer (score 2):

The result of both expressions is the same: an empty string. However, the first is more explicit, thus more readable.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. You can also see for yourself! That's the most reliable answer you can get. Just use a debugger. Execute the two lines and compare the result. But youshould rename the arrays. I use gcc/gdb and compile the following code

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char s[5] = {0};
    char t[5] = "";
    return 0;
}
```

via gcc -g test.c and then invoke gdb a.out. In gdb i enter

```
break 5
run
print s
```

the last statement is answered by gdb with the following output:

```
$1 = "\000\000\000\000"
```

i continue and enter "print t" and get accordingly

```
$2 = "\000\000\000\000"
```

which tells me that with my compiler of choice both statements result in the same result.

Comment: Matthias: that's not the most reliable method, as any behaviours that are undefined can vary between compiler implementations or due to differences in uninitialised memory content....

Comment: @tony-delroy i clarified and hope i made my point clearer (i didn't really get yours though...)

Comment: my point is that knowing what your program does on a particular run doesn't prove what the C++ Standard requires any executable generated from that source code by any C++ compiler to do.  If you want reliable code, you stick to what the Standard guarantees, as the observable program behaviour can vary.  For example, if you read from an uninitialised variable - `int x; std::cout << x << '\n';` - you may see the number you're expecting by chance (especially if you're expecting a 0), but re-run the program, or recompile it, and you may get different output....

Comment: @tony-delroy no doubt. but look at it the other way around. the standard says "x" and the very compiler you use says "y". thats what i had in mind when i wrote reliable... of course my answer may be more dedictad to beginners. and yours is for the professional deploying code that works on large variety of platforms and will be in use for decades. agreed?

Comment: I agree that there are a great many things a beginning programmer can learn by experimentation, but whether a suspected uninitialised variable happens to be 0 by luck or Standard guarantee isn't really one of them. Sequence points are another area that too many beginners try to learn about by experimentation. Anyway, have explained my concern - readers can see both sides... :-).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what have already been said:

```
char s[32] = "";
```

=

```
char s[32] = {'\0'};
```

=

```
char s[32] = {0};
```

=

```
char s[32] = {0, 0, 0, /* ...32 zeroes here*/ ,0 };
```

All of these will result in *exactly* the same machine code: a 32 byte array filled with all zeroes.